# joint in vb.net with sql server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, join

hi everyone i have two tables Patients([NumPatient],[NomPatient],[AdressePatient],[GSM],[Ville],[CIN]) and rdvs([num_rdv],[date_heure_rdv],[etat_rdv],[num_pat]).
num_pat is a foreign key in rdvs table .
i want to make a joint between the two tables in order to displaye the [NomPatient] in table Patients value according to the value of [num_pat] of the table rdvs i've tried to make it like this code shows but it doesn't work :

```
Private Sub Combonumrdv_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combonumrdv.SelectedIndexChanged
    Connection()
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "select NomPatient from Patients INNER JOIN rdvs on Patients.NumPatient = '" & Combonumrdv.SelectedValue & "' = rdvs.num_pat "
    Dim res As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    txtnompat.Text = res
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

i know that the probleme is in my sql request thanks .

Comment: Look at your query. Your join predicate has this "where x = y = z" That makes no sense. You should have it join on table1.value = table2.value and filter the rows with a where clause. You also should look at parameterizing your queries instead of directly executing user inputs.

Comment: i tried this also   cmd.CommandText = "select NomPatient from Patients INNER JOIN rdvs on Patients.NumPatient = rdvs.num_pat where rdvs.num_pat = '" & Combonumrdv.SelectedValue & "'"

Comment: NO. You don't put that value in the join predicate. You put it in the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you were trying to get this

> select NomPatient
>   from Patients INNER JOIN rdvs on Patients.NumPatient  = rdvs.num_pat 
>   WHERE rdvs.num_pat = '" &
>   Combonumrdv.SelectedValue & "'

in which you are joining the two tables basing on the foreign key and filtering on the content of a combo.

In any case, if the scenario is simply the one you're describing, you don't need to join the two tables but can get the same result using

> SELECT NomPatient 
>   FROM Patients 
>   WHERE NumPatient  = '" &Combonumrdv.SelectedValue & "'

Comment: Of course we don't know which table NomPatient comes from. Also, to the OP. You really need to parameterize that query. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: I get the info on the tables from the beginning of the question :).  You're right regarding the parametrization, i was just correcting the sql after a copy&paste, I'm not a vb.net expert and could only suppose the meaning. Moreover as a personal taste, I would prefer to use a different approach without coding a direct select in UI codebehind.

Comment: Agreed 100% on not having the data retrieval in the code behind. I rarely bother parsing through table definitions when they are all laid out in such a format. :)

Comment: I'm just a new one, trying to understand and doing things correctly i read even the small lines :)